# Java generics - use member method of unknown class

Tags: java, generics

So I have an Interface `MyInterface<T>` which has a method `String save(T obj)`
The implementing class has this definition `Animal<T> implements MyInterface<T>`. My Main function looks like this:

```
MyInterface<Cow> animal = new Animal<Cow>();
Cow cow = new Cow();
cow.setName("Rose");
animal.save(cow);
```

So far so good, `animal.save()` can only save Cows which is type-safe.

Now the problem. In my Animal class I have the save method, but before I save I want to know that my Cow has a name. The Cow class has a `getName()` method.

Save method:

```
@Override
public void save(T obj)
```

What would be an apropriate way to go from `T obj` to a Cow-object so I can use the member method `getName()`?

My idea is:

```
@Override
public void save(T obj)
{
        Object unknown = obj.getClass().newInstance();
        if (unknown instanceof Cow)
        {
            String name = ((Cow) unknown).getName();
        }
}
```

Is this "ok" java? I guess I could use reflection and search for all methods related to the `unknown` object as well..

**Update**
As long as I define `MyInterface<Cow> animal = new Animal<Cow>();` Like this I'm safe, but the problem apperas when it looks like this:

```
MyInterface<Object> animal = new Animal<Object>();
```

Then there is no `getName()` method....

Comment: Using `instanceof` to check the type of an object often means your code has a smell.  The whole point of coding to an interface is so that you can call `getName()` on _any_ matching generic object, without worrying that the object has the `getName()` method.

Comment: is your Cow class a subclass of Animal?

Comment: It is "ok", but hard to maintain. Imagine you now implement a `Dog`, you may want to check its `goodBoiScore()`. For a `Cat`, you may want to check its `meow()`,... For each of this new classes, you would have to create a new `if (... instanceof ...)`. This seems like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Could you explain what you are actually trying to do with e.g. the `cow`'s name?

Comment: Yes I don't like the instanceof, but feels scary to leave it out. I cant pass an object which isn't a Cow to the save method in the first place...

Comment: My question is if you specifically _only_ want this to happen for Cow objects, or for all classes that implement this interface? Could you not write a (virtual) getName() method in the interface of MyInterface or Animal so you can call this method without having to worry that the object has to be a Cow?

Comment: @Turing85 I was looking at the ArrayList source code. It works similar, but as Tim said, maybe the instanceof is not needed

Comment: @BakedInhalf could you point out which part of `ArrayList`'s source code you mean? There are some casts to `T` within `ArrayList`, but as far as I know, they are all type-safe, even if the backing Array is an `Object[]`. As far as I know, there are no `instanceof`-instructions within ArrayList (JDK 1.8, have not checked JDK 1.9).

Comment: @ChristopheLoeys That is one good idé. Will try it out

Comment: @Turing85 I figured out I don't need the cast as long as I define in angle brackets what class i'm working with. The problem arises when the definition looks like this: ´MyInterface<Object> animal = new Animal<Object>();´

Comment: If you use `Object` as generic parameter, you pretty much give up almost all type security =) to avoid this, we can use `extends` and `super` to restrict generic types. You may want to take a look at the [PECS mnemonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Comment: @Turing85 Whoha that was some heavy complex stuff =) I guess I can read that in my spare time just after Santa =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`instanceof` should be avoided wherever possible, and so should reflection.

I would add a separate interface which indicates whether something is in a saveable state. Your `Animal` class would then need to change it's generic type parameter to only allow saveable items.

```
interface Saveable
{
    boolean canSave();
}

public class Cow implements Saveable
{
    //...

    @Override
    boolean canSave()
    {
        return getName() != null && !getName().isEmpty();
    }
}

public class Animal<T extends Saveable> implements MyInterface<T>
{
    @Override
    public void save(T obj)
    {
        if (obj.canSave())
        {
            //whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That I didn't think of, really nice! I will try your approach. Didn't know a class could "extend" an interface on it's generic type!

Answer (score 4):

If you assume that all animals have a name then create an interface.

```
static interface HasName {
    String getName();
}
```

All objects having a name should then implements the interface

```
class Cow implements HasName{
    String name;

    Cow(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then modifying `Annimal` to allow all objects implementing the interface you will be able to get their names:

```
class Annimal<T extends HasName> {
    void save(T obj) {
        ...
        String name =  obj.getName();
    }
}
```

Even if the use of `instanceof` works, like in your post, it's a practice to avoid, because if one day you want to implement a new type of animal, let's say `Horse`, you will have to modify the implementation of your save method to add the `if (unknown instanceof Horse)` condition.

Comment: Nice approach. Too bad I can't accept more than one answer

Answer (score 2):

No, this is "not OK" Java. First because you want to avoid downcasts, but mainly for your idea to use reflection like this.

If that `getName()` functionality is really an essential part of your model, then consider placing it in its own interface for example.

Meaning: if at all, you should be doing something like

```
@Override
public void save(T obj) {
  if (obj instanceof NamedThingy) { 
    then cast ...
```

Comment: I guess I don't need the cast... it's not even possible to pass an object of Object() to the save method. As long as I define in angle-brackets what type I'm working with . Just saw that now :)

Comment: "not OK" - very subjective. Downcasting does happen from time to time. Sometimes you're stuck with code that isnt yours and you cant change, for example.

Comment: I was mainly concerned about using reflection - updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers are great and can be used without a doubt. But I still have something to suggest. While the others most time talked about a new interface and then invoke a method like `getName()` or `canSave` (which does work like a charm), I prefer using a custom tester, like a `Predicate<T>`.

I assume your `MyInterface` is like a service which saves an entity to a database or a similar data structure. Then you could adapt your class `Animal` like the following:

```
public class Animal<T> implements MyInterface<T>{
     private final Predicate<T> canSave;

     public Animal(Predicate<T> canSave){
         this.canSave = canSave;
     }

     @Override
     public void save(T obj){
         if(canSave.test(obj)){
              // your save logic
         }
     }
}
```

That way you define per instance of `Animal` a behaviour when that entity can be saved:

```
Animal<Cow> animal = new Animal<>(c -> c.getName() != null); // save only when name not null
Cow cow = new Cow();

animal.save(cow); // doesn't save because name is null

cow.setName("Rose");
animal.save(cow); // saves because name is set

animal = new Animal<>(c -> true); // save always

cow.setName(null);
animal.save(cow); // saves because it can always
```

Comment: I felt the `new interface` was the most convenient solution, but this was cool.

Comment: @BakedInhalf it really depends on your usecase. Because when you only have to check if the name is set, for every animal, then `new interface` is the best approach, because it's not overengineered. If you have different conditions though, then my answer would probably work the best